# What is the proper way to build to Android using Flutter via Unity AR Foundation?

Tags: flutter, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

Flutter doesn't have clear instructions on how to export to Android device.

I am building an AR Foundation app in Unity 2020.3.25 using echo3D as the 3D asset management backend. I'm on Windows. There are no clear instructions in their docs for how to actually build to Android. I believe this is different than the 'flutter widget' so there is no 'Flutter' button in my Unity menu. All dependencies are resolved so I'm ready to build but can't figure out how.

I was able to get as far as 'Export' in Unity and it exported just fine. But where do I put it and how do I get it on my actual Android device?

Comment: Did you Install the APK on Android Device (after export)?

Comment: I reinstalled, worked!